# click the child div but not the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a treeview with Jquery. Creating the first child nodes works pretty fine. But when I want to create a new div and make it a child of the child div, it does not work because the parent is still selected instead of the child div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    createEle("#nodeContainer", i);
  }
});

var currentSelectedNode = null;

function createEle(parent, title) {
  var container = $("<div></div>");
  container.addClass("node");
  container.attr("id", "treeViewNode" + title);
  container.html(title);
  container.click(function() {
    currentSelectedNode = container;
  });
  $(parent).append(container);
}

function newNode() {
  if (currentSelectedNode === null)
    currentSelectedNode = "#nodeContainer";

  createEle(currentSelectedNode, "child");
}

function deleteNode() {
  if (currentSelectedNode != null)
    $(currentSelectedNode).remove();
}
```

```css
#nodeContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.node {
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="newNode()">New Node</button>
<button onclick="deleteNode()">Delete Node</button>
<div id="nodeContainer"></div>
```

You can select a div container and add new child containers to it. But there is no way creating child containers for the current child containers.

So what I want to create is something like this

[image: Example]

Comment: Your description of the issue doesn't make a lot of sense given the code you've shown. You only create child elements at root level. It would be better if you could show or describe the behaviour you're trying to create as there's several improvements you can potentially make, such as removing the `on*` attributes and tidying up the jQuery logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) is what you need to prevent the click from traveling up the tree.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    createEle("#nodeContainer", i);
  }
});

var currentSelectedNode = null;

function createEle(parent, title) {
  var container = $("<div></div>");
  container.addClass("node");
  container.attr("id", "treeViewNode" + title);
  container.html(title);
  container.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    currentSelectedNode = container;
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
  $(parent).append(container);
}

function newNode() {
  if (currentSelectedNode === null)
    currentSelectedNode = "#nodeContainer";

  createEle(currentSelectedNode, "child");
}

function deleteNode() {
  if (currentSelectedNode != null)
    $(currentSelectedNode).remove();
}
```

```css
#nodeContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.node {
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="newNode()">New Node</button>
<button onclick="deleteNode()">Delete Node</button>
<div id="nodeContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the complete solution but I think it will gives you an idea

```
  if( document.getElementById('treeViewNodechild') ){ 
     var childEle = $('#treeViewNodechild');
     $(childEle).append(container);
  }
```

The trick is to monitor is the child id exist, if yes then append within the child if not append to parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    createEle("#nodeContainer", i);
  }
});

var currentSelectedNode = null;

function createEle(parent, title) {

 

  var container = $("<div></div>");
  container.addClass("node");
  container.attr("id", "treeViewNode" + title);
  container.html(title);
  container.click(function() {
    currentSelectedNode = container;
  });
  $(parent).append(container);
  
  
  //if child exist
  if( document.getElementById('treeViewNodechild') ){
     //console.log('child exist');
  
  var childEle = $('#treeViewNodechild');
  $(childEle).append(container);
  }
  
  
}

function newNode() {
  if (currentSelectedNode === null)
    currentSelectedNode = "#nodeContainer";

  createEle(currentSelectedNode, "child");
}

function deleteNode() {
  if (currentSelectedNode != null)
    $(currentSelectedNode).remove();
}
```

```css
#nodeContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.node {
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="newNode()">New Node</button>
<button onclick="deleteNode()">Delete Node</button>
<div id="nodeContainer"></div>
```